# Python SQL insert into Google Sheets stops at 26 values

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, streamlit

I've been working on building an app for a contest for some friends and I on Streamlit for the coming NHL season. The gist of it is that we make a series of predictions from a number of selectboxes, and these predictions get taken from the app that I've made and inserted into a row in a Google Sheet. Altogether, there are 53 values to go in the sheet - a name, a Discord handle, the timestamp of the entry, and then 50 player names to accomplish various tasks over the season (if you're familiar with the DownGoesBrown NHL prediction contest, its actually using that format).

The Streamlit docs that I was referring to recommended that I use `gsheetsdb` for the purpose of connecting my app to the Google Sheet, and that has been superceded by `Shillelagh`, so that's what I'm using. I have finished building the app's retrieval operations, and those work perfectly well, providing all 53 values for an entrant when requested. On the INSERT side though, I've run into a bit of a problem that I can't seem to find a way around. When I run my SQL statement to insert the 53 values into the Google Sheet, for some reason it always tops out at 26. I'm sure this is because a Google Sheet starts with 26 columns and you have to manually add more, but I've added more and even populated them with headings, yet I can't seem to get `Shillelagh` to understand that there are more than 26 columns, so the remaining columns just get left blank.

Here's the relevant portion of the code that I'm using.

Global variables used by both writing & retrieval operations:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    st.secrets["gcp_service_account"], 
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",],)
connection = connect(":memory:", adapter_kwargs={
    "gsheetsapi" : { 
    "service_account_info" : {
        "type" : st.secrets["gcp_service_account"]["type"],
        "project_id" : st.secrets["gcp_service_account"]["project_id"],
        "private_key_id" : st.secrets["gcp_service_account"]["private_key_id"],
        "private_key" : st.secrets["gcp_service_account"]["private_key"],
        "client_email" : st.secrets["gcp_service_account"]["client_email"],
        "client_id" : st.secrets["gcp_service_account"]["client_id"],
        "auth_uri" : st.secrets["gcp_service_account"]["auth_uri"],
        "token_uri" : st.secrets["gcp_service_account"]["token_uri"],
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url" : st.secrets["gcp_service_account"]["auth_provider_x509_cert_url"],
        "client_x509_cert_url" : st.secrets["gcp_service_account"]["client_x509_cert_url"],
        }
    },
})
```

And then from the writing operations, this code activates once the Submit Entry button is hit:

```
if submitted:
    # Create timestamp of submission
    submission_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    # Use Shillelagh to insert the info to the spreadsheet
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sheet_url = st.secrets["private_gsheets_url"]
    query = f'INSERT INTO "{sheet_url}" VALUES ("{entrant_name}", "{entrant_discord}", "{submission_time}", "{q1a1}", "{q1a2}", "{q1a3}", "{q1a4}", "{q1a5}" ... "{q10a1}", "{q10a2}", "{q10a3}", "{q10a4}", "{q10a5}")'
    cursor.execute(query)
    st.write(f"{entrant_name}, your entry associated with {entrant_discord} has been submitted as of {submission_time} with the following selections:  \nQuestion 1:{q1a1}, {q1a2}, {q1a3}, {q1a4}, {q1a5}  ... \nQuestion 10:{q10a1}, {q10a2}, {q10a3}, {q10a4}, {q10a5}")
```

I've never built a web app like this before, so I've been doing a lot of stumbling through the darkness until I manage to finagle things together. I feel like I'm super close here and just missing something obvious, if someone could please help me out and push me in the right direction to make `Shillelagh` and the Google Sheet talk to each other to recognize how many columns are actually available to be written into.